# Changing the weight function of a generating function?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Let $S$ be a set of objects, and suppose $w$ is a weight function on $S$ with generating function $\Phi_S(x)$. Let $w^*$ be a new weight function for $S$ defined by $w^*(a)=5w(a)+3$ for all $a\in S$, and let $\Phi^*_S(x)$ be the generating function for $S$ with respect to $w^*$. Express $\Phi^*_S(x)$ in terms of $\Phi_S(x)$.

How would I do this problem? Is there some general method for linearly changing the weight function? Google seems to be *extremely* unhelpful with my introductory combinatorics course.

Comment: This is $x^3 \Phi_S(x^5)$ by inspection.

Comment: How did you inspect it? ;)

Comment: Well if you take just one term of $\Phi$ it is given by $x^{w(a)}$. So to get $5w(a)$ use $(x^5)^{w(a)}$ and for  $3+5w(a)$ use $x^3(x^5)^{w(a)}.$